# VBA how to copy corresponding column values from another workbook if values matches

Tags: excel, vba

I have done several research regarding the excel vba. But i still coudn't find the solution to my problem.

The reason i use macros is because it have to be done weekly. What the macros should do is when the values matches column A (column ***item***) from both workbook, it will copy the Unallocation stock from workbook 2 (column H) to (column C) in workbook 1.

Workbook 2
[image: IMAGE of workbook 2]

Workbook 1
[image: IMAGE of workbook 1]

Below, partial code that is not working. Feel free to share your own code because i'm not good in VBA as well. (if possible please include comment so i easy to understand)

```
  FindString = ws1.Range("A" & j) 'stock item number
  If Trim(FindString) <> "" Then ' if item number not equal to blank
    With ws3.Range("A:A") 'searches all of column A of sum up sheet
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=FindString, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.count), _
                       LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
         '---If intersite exists in ws3
                '---------VLOOKUP ------------

        'If (ws1.Range("H" & j).Value > ws3.Range("B" & j).Value) Then

          ' here = Rng.Row


            'ws1.Range("A" & j & ":R" & j).Copy ws4.Range("A" & lrow4)              'Copy stockworkbook range A(j) until R(j)  until paste to worksheet Output
            'lrow4 = ws4.Cells(ws4.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row + 1                 'lastrow tambah 1

          ws1.Range("H" & j).Copy ws3.Range("c" & lrow4)
          lrow4 = ws3.Cells(ws4.Rows.count, "c").End(xlUp).Row + 1
```

[Image: No error in coding but the output is wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/001CA.png)

[Image: Result of blank output in column C](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oymh.png)

Comment: What does not work about the provided code? Be specific so we can help

Comment: @urdearboy the output seems to be incorrect. i already update the output.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

WIP
WIP: reference workbook.worksheet ist not possible
WIP

```
    Dim i as Integer 'will run through workbook 2
    Dim j as Integer 'will run through workbook 1

    Dim wbOne as Workbook
    Set wbOne = Workbook("WorkbookOne")
    Dim wbTwo as Workbook
    Set wbTwo = Workbook("WorkbookTwo") 'replace with correct naming

    Dim wsOne as Worksheet
    Set wsOne = Worksheets("WorksheetOne")
    Dim wsTwo as Worksheet
    Set wsTwo = Worksheets("WorksheetTwo")


    for i = 1 to 1000 'length wb1
        for j = 1 to 10000 'length wb2
            if wbTwo.wsTwo.cells(i,1).value = wbOne.wsOne.cells(j,1).value then 
                wbTwo.wsTwo.cells(i,3).value = wbOne.wsOne.cells(j,8).value
                exit for 'exit j loop because match was found
            end if
        next j
    next i
```

you can adjust the length of your workbooks dynamically. If the if-statement is not clear, just ask.
Another tip: you seem to have a large amount of data, so a double-loop might take a long time to compute. You can make this program **drastically** faster by saving all of the data in arrays and then execute the double loop on the arrays.

Comment: Sir, thanks for the code and i totally understand the code. There is no error in coding when i run but the output is not showing (blank). i will update the( results ) as picture above. Do you know what error i could make?

Comment: Hello Muhammad, I made an error. It is not possible to make this reference: workbook.worksheet. I will correct my answer later

Comment: sir can you help?

Comment: Hello Muhammad, do you still need help or did you figure it out?